How to restore mail account settings to replacement iphone?
Have a first generation iPhone SE that I am completely happy with, except that it's battery is starting to fail and is very clearly at the end of its functional life.  Rather than get a new phone or replace the battery, I happen to have an additional first gen iPhone SE that has been in its box in a drawer for years and is basically brand new.
I fired it up, updated it to the latest iOS, then logged in to iCloud to let everything begin to transfer over.  Everything seems fine with one exception: Mail.  Only the iCloud email address is there, none of the others (gmail, an old AT&T email, yahoo, etc) got imported.
I know I can just re-enter the login details for each account and everything should come back again via IMAP, but I'd rather not have to go to all that trouble.  I fully expected everything to come over including all my email accounts.
How can I get them all restored over from the old phone, to the new phone?

To answer my own question... I ended up just doing a new full restore.  Since the phone had previously been turned on and the initial setup steps gone through but nothing else, I was never prompted to restore from a backup and so only iCloud came over after logging in.  But now after a full restore, I was prompted to choose a backup to restore from and everything restored including the email accounts.
